# std::fstream crashes after main while using pre-allocated memory

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I currently have a `std::ofstream` being created on the stack, and when it allocates off a global `operator new` that assigns it memory from a pre-allocated buffer the program will crash after `main` completes citing `std::locale0 : line 59. Read Access Violation. nodeptr was 0x...` as the program crash point. `nodeptr`'s memory address is a real address. I have no idea why this is happening, and I can only assume it was because I misunderstand what the allocations are actually doing.

This behaviour happens on a `release` build tested on `MSVC Version 19.10.25019 x86`, building on `debug` has the program complete without a crash. Dr. Memory reports no leaks in debug mode.

Minimal Code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

std::uint8_t *byte = static_cast<std::uint8_t*>(malloc(134217728)); // 134217728 = 128 MiB

void *operator new(size_t bytes) throw(std::bad_alloc)
    {
        return static_cast<void*>(byte); // Tested empirically, and this is only called once so this shouldnt be a cause of a problem
    }

void operator delete(void *memory) throw()
    {}

int main()
    {
        std::ofstream out("abc");

        free(byte);
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't appear that the replacement new is called in a debug build, at least in Visual Studio 2017. In a release build the replacement new is only called once, and the crash seems to be when cleaning up a locale which matches your description. The comments in the code talk about destroying lazy facets. If you look a little higher in the file you'll see that in a debug build there's a replacement new/delete for the class.

Comment: @RetiredNinja It seems like this is a Visual C++ bug regarding custom allocations and std::locale. "std::locale in CRT assumes all facets to be allocated on CRT heap" - a bug report

Answer (score 0):

There are two obvious bugs:

1. What if `operator new` is called more than once? What if the constructor of `out` constructs a sub-object?
2. You free `byte` while `out` is still in scope. When `out`'s destructor runs, you've already returned its memory to the system.

Try this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

std::uint8_t *byte = static_cast<std::uint8_t*>(malloc(134217728)); // 134217728 = 128 MiB

void *operator new(size_t bytes) throw(std::bad_alloc)
    {
        static int offset = 0;
        void * ret = static_cast<void*>(byte + offset);
        offset += 16 * ((bytes + 15) / 16);
        return ret;
    }

void operator delete(void *memory) throw()
    {}

int main()
    {
        {
            std::ofstream out("abc");
        }

        free(byte);
    }
```

Comment: Exact same exception as before. For 1) That was because I wanted the smallest code possible, and I forgot to explain that I tested and made sure that `new` was called only once.

Comment: Re. (1), it seems likely that setting up all the apparatus for using a stream and other startup procedures will involve multiple allocations

Comment: @M.M I meant to never give out the same address twice (unless for allocation of size zero) and to align to 16 byte boundary. (Which I obviously got wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

[It appears as it is a Visual Studio bug regarding custom allocations and `std::locale`.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/750951/std-locale-implementation-in-crt-assumes-all-facets-to-be-allocated-on-crt-heap-and-crashes-in-destructor-in-debug-mode-if-a-facet-was-allocated-by-a-custom-allocator)

Comment: That bug does not appear to be the same issue you're having.  Similar, but not exact. Since the program is exiting anyway, there's really no harm in not freeing that block since it will get cleaned up anyway, but leak detectors may complain. I always want to free everything even though I'm exiting too.